# Open any email attachment inside the ios app

Tags: swift

[image: Document Type]I want to open any email attachments with my iOS app. Means from my iOS app I want to open email and if there is any attachments(like pdf), I want to open this attachment with my app.I am able to open email app from my app with the following code

```
if let mailURL = URL(string: "message:") {
           if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(mailURL) {
               UIApplication.shared.open(mailURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
           }
       }
```

After that how to open any attachments inside the iOS app. can any one help me. Can I save the attachments to my documents Directory?

Comment: Do you mean you want to add your app in the list of apps that Mail shows you when you tap an attachment ?

Comment: Actually my requirement is from my app I will go to the mail box. If any attachment present there, I have to open it with my app. Not only I want to open it with my app, but also I want to save the file in my documents directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Actually my requirement is from my app I will go to the mail box. If any attachment present there, I have to open it with my app. Not only I want to open it with my app, but also I want to save the file in my documents directory.

You can't tell the Mail app what to do so what you want is not exactly possible.

What you can do is add your app in the "Open In" menu by supporting some file types. So that when the user taps the attachment your app will appear in the list of apps.

You can do that this way:

1. Add the file types your app can handle. Follow the instructions here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1587/_index.html
2. Once 1. is done add the following function in your AppDelegate:

```swift
func application(application: UIApplication, handleOpenURL url: NSURL) -> Bool {
       // do what you want with file
}
```

To save the file in your app's document directory you can see how it's done here:
https://programmingwithswift.com/save-file-to-documents-directory-with-swift/

Comment: Hi @Moucheg. i am unable to find Uniform Type Identifier (UTI) for document type.i have added a screen shot in my question, can you look into it and let me know where i am doing wrong.

Comment: Thanks @Moucheg for your response. Now it is working fine. Previously some issue with configuring the document. But i resolved it.

Comment: @TapanRaut Glad you could figure it out (was busy yesterday, didn't have time to visit SO)